# OkHttp Interceptor using OkHttpClient without dependency cycle

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit, okhttp, dagger-2

I'm using Retrofit and Dagger 2. I have implemented an OkHttp `Interceptor` for adding the oauth token. In the case there is no oauth token or the timestamp is invalid, I request a new one (via the Retrofit service) before the actual request is carried out.

This creates a dependency cycle where the Retrofit service requires the `Interceptor` but the `Interceptor` also requires the Retrofit service (for retrieving the oauth token).

Example for the `Interceptor` (for simplification it always requests the token via `restService#refreshAccessToken`):

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request originalRequest = chain.request();
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder();

    String authHeader = "Bearer " + restService.refreshAccessToken();
    requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
    return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Interceptor` will need to inject itself in the `Interceptor#intercept()` method. This way your Retrofit service (including the `OkHttpClient` with the added interceptor) dependency can be satisfied without a dependency cycle.

My `NetworkComponent` (which provides my Retrofit service) lives in my `Application` class. Here is an example of injecting it using an Application `Context`.

```
public class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Inject RestService restService;

    public AuthInterceptor(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        // Inject Retrofit service
        ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext())
                .getNetworkComponent().inject(this);

        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder();

        String authHeader = "Bearer " + restService.refreshAccessToken();
        requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

You could also just set a local variable without injecting the entire class, possibly getting better performance.

```
RestService restService = InjectHelper.getNetworkComponent(mContext).restService();
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Is there a downside (e.g.: performance) because every request/intercept causes an injection? Also the Application has to expose the NetworkComponent, which seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: Dagger 2 is built to be fast because it uses only generated code, so it's essentially just going to call some method that sets your `RestService`. I've added an alternate way that avoids injecting the entire class to my answer. It doesn't have to be `Application` providing it, but what else would provide your app `Singleton` components? Storing your app-wide components in Application is common practice on all the Dagger 2 stuff I have read.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer Lazy injection, which is a bit cleaner

```java
public class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    Lazy<RestService> restService;

    @Inject
    public AuthInterceptor(Lazy<RestService> restService) {
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder();

        String authHeader = "Bearer " + restService.get().refreshAccessToken();
        requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is very clean! Does this still need an `@Inject` annotation?

Comment: It's up to you. No if you write provider